# changing character speed in pygames

Tags: python, pygame

Im following this tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/24252/beginning-game-programming-for-teens-with-python#comments

here is the full code:

```
# 1 - Import library
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math
import random

# 2 - Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
keys = [False, False, False, False]
playerpos=[100,100]
acc=[0,0]
arrows=[]
badtimer=100
badtimer1=0
badguys=[[640,100]]
healthvalue=194
pygame.mixer.init()

# 3 - Load image
player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")
grass = pygame.image.load("resources/images/grass.png")
castle = pygame.image.load("resources/images/castle.png")
arrow = pygame.image.load("resources/images/bullet.png")
badguyimg1 = pygame.image.load("resources/images/badguy.png")
badguyimg=badguyimg1
healthbar = pygame.image.load("resources/images/healthbar.png")

health = pygame.image.load("resources/images/health.png")
gameover = pygame.image.load("resources/images/gameover.png")
youwin = pygame.image.load("resources/images/youwin.png")
# 3.1 - Load audio
hit = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/explode.wav")
enemy = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/enemy.wav")
shoot = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/shoot.wav")
hit.set_volume(0.05)
enemy.set_volume(0.05)
shoot.set_volume(0.05)
pygame.mixer.music.load('resources/audio/moonlight.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.25)

# 4 - keep looping through
running = 1
exitcode = 0
while running:
    badtimer-=1
    # 5 - clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(0)
    # 6 - draw the player on the screen at X:100, Y:100
    for x in range(0, int(width/grass.get_width()+1)):
        for y in range(0, int(height/grass.get_height()+1)):
            screen.blit(grass,(x*100,y*100))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,30))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,135))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,240))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,345 ))
    # 6.1 - Set player position and rotation
    position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    angle = math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos[0]+26))
    playerrot = pygame.transform.rotate(player, 360-angle*57.29)
    playerpos1 = (playerpos[0]-playerrot.get_rect().width/2, playerpos[1]-playerrot.get_rect().height/2)
    screen.blit(playerrot, playerpos1) 
    # 6.2 - Draw arrows
    for bullet in arrows:
        index=0
        velx=math.cos(bullet[0])*10
        vely=math.sin(bullet[0])*10
        bullet[1]+=velx
        bullet[2]+=vely
        if bullet[1]<-64 or bullet[1]>640 or bullet[2]<-64 or bullet[2]>480:
            arrows.pop(index)
        index+=1
        for projectile in arrows:
            arrow1 = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 360-projectile[0]*57.29)
            screen.blit(arrow1, (projectile[1], projectile[2]))
    # 6.3 - Draw badgers
    if badtimer==0:
        badguys.append([640, random.randint(50,430)])
        badtimer=100-(badtimer1*2)
        if badtimer1>=35:
            badtimer1=35
        else:
            badtimer1+=5
    index=0
    for badguy in badguys:
        if badguy[0]<-64:
            badguys.pop(index)
        badguy[0]-=7
        # 6.3.1 - Attack castle
        badrect=pygame.Rect(badguyimg.get_rect())
        badrect.top=badguy[1]
        badrect.left=badguy[0]
        if badrect.left<64:
            hit.play()
            healthvalue -= random.randint(5,20)
            badguys.pop(index)
        #6.3.2 - Check for collisions
        index1=0
        for bullet in arrows:
            bullrect=pygame.Rect(arrow.get_rect())
            bullrect.left=bullet[1]
            bullrect.top=bullet[2]
            if badrect.colliderect(bullrect):
                enemy.play()
                acc[0]+=1
                badguys.pop(index)
                arrows.pop(index1)
            index1+=1
        # 6.3.3 - Next bad guy
        index+=1
    for badguy in badguys:
        screen.blit(badguyimg, badguy)
    # 6.4 - Draw clock
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    survivedtext = font.render(str((90000-pygame.time.get_ticks())/60000)+":"+str((90000-pygame.time.get_ticks())/1000%60).zfill(2), True, (0,0,0))
    textRect = survivedtext.get_rect()
    textRect.topright=[635,5]
    screen.blit(survivedtext, textRect)
    # 6.5 - Draw health bar
    screen.blit(healthbar, (5,5))
    for health1 in range(healthvalue):
        screen.blit(health, (health1+8,8))
    # 7 - update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 8 - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check if the event is the X button 
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            # if it is quit the game
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_w:
                keys[0]=True
            elif event.key==K_a:
                keys[1]=True
            elif event.key==K_s:
                keys[2]=True
            elif event.key==K_d:
                keys[3]=True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                keys[0]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_a:
                keys[1]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_s:
                keys[2]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_d:
                keys[3]=False
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            shoot.play()
            position=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            acc[1]+=1
            arrows.append([math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos1[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos1[0]+26)),playerpos1[0]+32,playerpos1[1]+32])

    # 9 - Move player
    if keys[0]:
        playerpos[1]-=5
    elif keys[2]:
        playerpos[1]+=5
    if keys[1]:
        playerpos[0]-=5
    elif keys[3]:
        playerpos[0]+=5

    #10 - Win/Lose check
    if pygame.time.get_ticks()>=90000:
        running=0
        exitcode=1
    if healthvalue<=0:
        running=0
        exitcode=0
    if acc[1]!=0:
        accuracy=acc[0]*1.0/acc[1]*100
    else:
        accuracy=0
# 11 - Win/lose display        
if exitcode==0:
    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    text = font.render("Accuracy: "+str(accuracy)+"%", True, (255,0,0))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery+24
    screen.blit(gameover, (0,0))
    screen.blit(text, textRect)
else:
    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    text = font.render("Accuracy: "+str(accuracy)+"%", True, (0,255,0))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery+24
    screen.blit(youwin, (0,0))
    screen.blit(text, textRect)
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Its not clear how the speed of the badger is altered in this game, could anyone suggest how?
The full package with images is downloadable on the website:

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to put this code into functions, so that it will be much easier to read.
The line you have been looking for is:

```
badguy[0]-=7
```

which moves the badguy 7 pixels to the left.
For easier configuration, you could add a variable at the top of the script `BADGER_SPEED=7`
and change the line to:

```
badguy[0]-=BADGER_SPEED
```

The badgers are generated here:

```
badguys.append([640, random.randint(50,430)])
```

This adds a new list of size 2 to the badguys list. These two components are the badger positions.

Comment: Could you tell me where the position of the badgers are set?

Comment: Ive tired changing that but nothing happens, i want it so the badgers come from the air not the left hand side of the screen. Been at this for a couple of hours :(

Comment: Try changing the line where he moves to `badguy[1]-=7` and the place where they are generated. But this makes no sense, since they will never reach you.

Comment: what do you mean? Ive changed that to badguy[1]-=2 
How would i change it so it comes from the air?

Comment: could you define "coming from air"?

Comment: as in comming from the top of the screen rather than the left hand side of the screen

Comment: they start from the right, and move to the left - the x coordinate is decreased (point of origin is at top left corner) For them to come from the top, you need to set their position above the screen, and change the movement to ADD to the y coordinate.